# execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'. firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I connected my app to firebase and it was launching just fine. But when imported two packages:
firebase_auth: ^4.17.3
cloud_firestore: ^4.15.3

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :firebase_auth) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Muhammad Yousuf\Desktop\Flutter Projects\firebase_app\build\firebase_auth\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :cloud_firestore) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Muhammad Yousuf\Desktop\Flutter Projects\firebase_app\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :firebase_core) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Muhammad Yousuf\Desktop\Flutter Projects\firebase_app\build\firebase_core\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
```

I have tried:

- enabling multidex
- android jetifier
- minsdkversion 21

Still the app wont launch. Both the dependencies are upto date and so is flutter sdk.